# How to bind an xml sitemap string to asp:menu in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

In my ASP.NET Page_load I have this code:

> ```
>   SiteMenu.DataSource = new XmlDataSource();
>   ((XmlDataSource)SiteMenu.DataSource).ID = "menu";
>   ((XmlDataSource)SiteMenu.DataSource).Data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><siteMap>   <siteMapNode title=\"default\" description=\"my title\"  url=\"http://www.google.com\"/></siteMap>";
>   SiteMenu.DataBind();
> ```

Where SiteMenu is an Asp:menu control.
But for some reason I'm getting a menu with one element with name "siteMap" and a child element with name "siteMapNode".

I would like to have only one element (rappresented by the ) with title "default".
Any Idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry Uince, didn't realize you're loading a remote sitemap,.

Comment: your link (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/PopulatingMenuControlASP2.aspx) was useful. Using the last part of the article I'm building the dataset from the string not the file but the problem is that for some reason is loading all the xml in one table :/